# How can I convert this time format into the unix timestamp in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

The time is given in this format `t=2015-10-01 23:10:11`. I tried using the following code, but it throws an error: `Time.parse(t).to_i`. So, how do I convert it?

Comment: Do you have a variable named `t` or is `t=` actually in the string? What's the error message?

Comment: I actually don't have any variable `t`. I just introduced it so that I wouldn't have to write `Time.parse(2015-10-01 23:10:11).to_i`, which looks ugly. But I had to write it anyway at the end of the day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. You forgot `require 'time'`

```
require 'time'
t="2015-10-01 23:10:11" 
Time.parse(t).to_i
#  => 1443766211
```

By the way, please always post the error. Otherwise we have to guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your t as a String
`t='2015-10-01 23:10:11'`

Now you can both

`DateTime.parse t`

`=> Thu, 01 Oct 2015 23:10:11 +0000`

and

`Time.parse t`

`=> 2015-10-01 23:10:11 +0100`

and than call `.to_i` on any of it:

`Time.parse(t).to_i`  or  `DateTime.parse(t).to_i`

Answer (score 0):

```
Time.parse('t=2015-10-01 23:10:11'.split('=').last).to_i
```